# How to run next fetch on timer thread after previous fetch completed?

Tags: java, multithreading, timertask, java-threads

I have a java application.When the application starts a timer thread is starting to run and keeping the app updated with api. This thread is triggered every one minute.
But the program takes about 15 minutes to bring all the records from the app when the user logs in for the first time.

Once all the entries in the first login have arrived, the thread will continue to work as usual and keep the new records coming.

Since the data coming from the user's first login to the system is large, the data is processed in 15 minutes. This means that it will be triggered 15 times within 15 minutes. I've protected the method in which Thread works with a synchronize keyword.
There's something else I need to do.

After the previous fetch of Thread, the other fetch to run.

Is there a mistake as logic.

My Timer thread code blok as follows;

```
final Timer timer = new Timer("Sikke Timer Task");
    long delay = SikkeConstant.THREAD_DELAY;
    long intervalPeriod = SikkeConstant.INTERVAL_PERIOD; //60sec
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* if (_System.shouldThreadContinueToWork) { */
            try {
                new EchoPostHandler().jsonrpc.methods.syncTx();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error on sikke thread : " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            /* } */
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, intervalPeriod);
```

Comment: Perhaps, you want to use `schedule` instead of `scheduleAtFixedRate`. However, you should not use this `TimerTask` legacy. Use a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead. The behavior of `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate` may be much closer to your intention.

Comment: @Holger thanks for your reply bro. ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate did not know this. I'm going to search, try and answer it in a short time.